# Sort list of dates by year & quarter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, sorting

Let's say I have a list:

```
Date = ['2015-Q1, '2013-Q4', '2017-Q2', '2018-Q1']
```

How can I sort it into chronological order such that:

```
Date = ['2013-Q4','2015-Q1','2017-Q2','2018-Q1']
```

Comment: This is tagged `pandas` but question only refers to `list`. Can you please clarify the format of your input & output? And whether you are happy with using 3rd party libraries?

Comment: The nature of that format means `sorted(Date)` should always work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `natsort`
[*natsort provides a function natsorted that helps sort lists “naturally” (“naturally” is rather ill-defined, but in general it means sorting based on meaning and not computer code point)*](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

```
import natsort
natsort.natsorted(Date)
Out[103]: ['2013-Q4', '2015-Q1', '2017-Q2', '2018-Q1']
```

Comment: Nice answer, this would be the "natural" answer ;-) However, there's something special about these strings.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I would say using pandas is more safety : -)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```
import pandas as pd

date = ['2015-Q1', '2013-Q4', '2017-Q2', '2018-Q1']

res = sorted(date, key=pd.to_datetime)
```

Result:

```
print(res)

['2013-Q4' '2015-Q1' '2017-Q2' '2018-Q1']
```

Comment: Very straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

These are periods. You'll want to generate a PeriodIndex and then call `sort_values`.

```
p = pd.PeriodIndex(['2013-Q4','2015-Q1','2017-Q2','2018-Q1'], freq='Q')    
p.sort_values() # p = p.sort_values() # np.sort(p)
```

```
PeriodIndex(['2013Q4', '2015Q1', '2017Q2', '2018Q1'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.to_datetime(Date).sort_values().to_period('Q')
```

Output:

```
PeriodIndex(['2013Q4', '2015Q1', '2017Q2', '2018Q1'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

Or like this if you want it back to strings:

```
pd.to_datetime(Date).sort_values().to_period('Q').strftime('%Y-Q%q')
array(['2013-Q4', '2015-Q1', '2017-Q2', '2018-Q1'], dtype='<U6')
```